# jquery .ui-selectable with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with fixed height

```
<div style="height:300px; overflow-y:scroll">
    <div class="selectable_div">
        ....
    </div> 
</div>
```

And I init selectable like this:

```
$( ".selectable_div" ).selectable({
```

But when  I select content in .selectable_div scroll gets blocked and div is not scrolling. I want it to scroll while selecting on mouse wheel and when I just select and hold selection and move mouse down.
What do I do?
I found a plugin but don't want really to use 3d party plugins cause they might break something

UPD : the entire snippet if u ask(it very big, so I don't think it will help)

```
$( ".selectable_wrap" ).selectable({
    filter: ".word_item",
    cancel: '.cancel_selection',
    stop: function(){
        self.words.filter(x => x.selected).forEach(function(w){
            w.selected = false
        })
        self.words_ids=[]
        // alert($( ".ui-selected.word_item").size())  
        $( ".ui-selected.word_item", this ).each(function() {
            let word_index = $(this).attr('data-count')
            word = self.words[word_index]
            word.selected = true
            self.words_ids.push(word.id)
        });
        self.get_phrases_by_words(JSON.stringify(self.words_ids))
    },
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: It would help to see the entire snippet?

Comment: @zak see update..